# How to use declared variables in INNER SELECT Statement in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

#### How to use SELECT Sub-Query in alias for a column?

Here's my script:-

```
/*Declaring variables:*/
SET period= '3';
SET smryseg=concat('sku',$period,'_smry');
SET spend= concat('sku',$period,'')
/*Printing it:*/
SELECT $period;                   /* #O/P: 3 */
SELECT $smryseg;                  /* #O/P: sku3_smry */
SELECT $spend;                    /* #O/P: sku3_spend */

/*now I want to use this variable in my INNER SELECT query:*/

create table IDENTIFIER ($smryseg) as
SELECT sum(spend) as (SELECT $spend)
FROM my_table;
```

Here, the last query is giving me an error, I also tried using *IDENTIFIER*, *CONCAT*, *SUBSRING*, *$* ,*removing parenthesis* and much more.
I just want the name of column 'sum(spend)' obtained as 'sku3_spend' i.e in dynamic format

Comment: Take a closer look at your definition for $spend. While the comments show that its value is "sku3_spend", the definition actually sets it to "sku3". Your concat has a blank string at the end. Is the column name actually "sku3_spend"?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the column afterwards.  Here's a self-contained example:

```
set spend_col='sku3_spend';
create or replace table t as select sum(spend) as x from values(1),(2),(3) s(spend);
alter table t rename column x to identifier($spend_col);
```

UPDATE

You can store dynamically named columns in an object:

```
set spend_col='sku3_spend';

create or replace table t as 
    select object_construct($spend_col, sum(spend)) data 
    from values(1),(2),(3) s(spend);

select data:sku3_spend from t;
```

Comment: I already tried this and it works too, but what if I only have select access to it? Also I don't want to create another table which I already did. 
BTW Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you do `select sum(spend) as value, $spend as label ...`?  Or dynamic SQL.  That's all I got.

Comment: Actually one more idea -- Store variably named columns in an OBJECT column.  I added an example to the answer.  Hope that helps.